# Leaflet geosearch with OpenStreetMapProvider - Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Whenever I type a letter in the input box, I am getting this error in my console.
It is failing in the 'autoSearch' function of the geo-search library.
I am using OpenStreetMapProviders. And here is my code snippet

```
const provider = new OpenStreetMapProvider({});
const search = new GeoSearchControl({
    provider: provider,
    showMarker: true,
    autoClose: true,
    keepResult: true
});
map.addControl(search);
```

[image: Screenshot of console error]

Comment: thanks, @Fake Design, I am a newbie here.

Comment: I figured out that my parent page container is taking the control of all the events on the page and it is becoming the target value of all the HTML controls on the page and this is causing the issue. Maybe this is due to the context of webcomponent (my parent page)  vs non-webcomponent (geo-search)